# Sum a measure of LastNonEmpty in GrandTotal in Microsoft SSAS

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, olap, measure

I am new to the OLAP, not sure how to sum the LastNonEmpty measure values in Grand Total, but keep LastNonEmpty values in other cells. like the following

```
Column 1    Column 2     Measure 
A           a            1
            b            2
            c   
            Total        2
B           a            4
            b     
            c     
            Total        4
Grand Total              6
```

Comment: Aggregation in MDX happens automatically. What exactly are your Dimensions and Measures?

Comment: The dimension for the table has 2 tiers. In the subtotal, try to have the Measure-LastNonEmpty for Dimension-Column1 calculated by Dimension-Column2. But in the grand total, is it possible to add all the subetotals with some customization?